# Code outside of if then doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

In an application I'm working on. The code outside if then isn't working. How should I achieve that target. For example when I try to place first two lines outside if else. It doesn't work.

Also how can I put repetitive code in some variable and call it with if else. For example this one `$(this).before(leftArrowHTML);`

```
$('.lessonNavigation ').on('click', 'li', function () {
if ($(this).is('.assess')) {
    $('.lessonNavigation li').not('.assess').attr('class', 'dn');
    $('.lessonNavigation li.assess').attr('class', 'dn assess');
    $(this).attr('class', 'activeLesson assess');
    $(this).prev().addClass('expanded left');
    $(this).next().addClass('expanded right');
    $(this).before(leftArrowHTML);
    $(this).after(rightArrowHTML);

} else if ($(this).is('.new')) {
    $('.lessonNavigation li').not('.assess').attr('class', 'dn');
    $('.lessonNavigation li.assess').attr('class', 'dn assess');
    $(this).attr('class', 'activeLesson');
    $(this).next().attr('class', 'expanded right brw');
    $(this).next().next().attr('class', 'expanded right');
    $(this).before(leftArrowHTML);
    $(this).after(rightArrowHTML);
    $('.arrow.left').attr('class', 'inactiveRightArrow');
}
});
```

Comment: close you bracket properly if ($(this).is('.assess')){
and use else if instead of else.

Comment: Most likely you should put those first two lines *above* the if, not below it; because the rest of the code may make changes to the document.

Comment: _"Code outside of if then doesn't work"_ ~ but you don't show any code outside of an if/then.  Are you trying to tell us that your `click` handler is not working the way you want?  Please write a better question that explains what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

**else** does not take a condition, you must use **else if**, also you are missing a closing parenthesis.

```
} else if ($(this).is('.new')) {
```

EDIT: you are also missing a closing bracket on your original **if** statement

```
if ($(this).is('.assess')) {
```

["elseif" syntax in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005614/elseif-syntax-in-javascript)

Comment: @user3693250, please be more careful when posting your code.  Your mistake wasted this user's time for answering.  An answer you rendered as meaningless by subsequently editing your question with his code.

Answer (score 1):

Just move them outside the `if`, but not outside the `click` callback, which is providing a value for `this`.

```
$('.lessonNavigation ').on('click', 'li', function () {

    if ($(this).is('.assess')) {
        $(this).attr('class', 'activeLesson assess');
        $(this).prev().addClass('expanded left');
        $(this).next().addClass('expanded right');
    } else if ($(this).is('.new')) {
        $(this).attr('class', 'activeLesson');
        $(this).next().attr('class', 'expanded right brw');
        $(this).next().next().attr('class', 'expanded right');
        $('.arrow.left').attr('class', 'inactiveRightArrow');
    }

    $('.lessonNavigation li.assess').attr('class', 'dn assess');
    $('.lessonNavigation li').not('.assess').attr('class', 'dn');
    $(this).before(leftArrowHTML);
    $(this).after(rightArrowHTML);
});
```