# Where is ther unexpected Syntax error?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

The console states that there is an unexpected { in my code. I went over the syntax several times and cannot seem to find it.

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper, or scissors?");

var computerChoice = Math.random(1);

if (computerChoice <= 0.33){
    computerChoice = "rock";
} elseif (computerChoice <= 0.67 && computerChoice >= 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}
```

Comment: `else if`, not `elseif`

Comment: @j08691: Answer, not comment.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - It's a typo, vote to close -- don't answer.

Comment: @j08691: _You_ answered! In the wrong place... Double wrong by your logic. Furthermore, how do you know it's a typo?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I voted to close as a typo *and* pointed out the problem o the user wasn't left wondering why. I could answer and mark it as a community wiki though. And it's a typo, regardless if it was intentional or not. Questions like these don't need formal answer and should be closed.

Comment: So you say "don't answer" but also provide an answer...... I don't get that. At all. If you think the question doesn't belong here then _don't answer it whatsoever, at all_. Certainly, though, it goes back to this for me: answers do not go in comments. Ever. And as for your "typo" comment that is simply nonsense: typos are by definition unintentional. I think you're mistaking "very small, isolated misunderstanding or error" with this invented "unintentional typo"! :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I don't see what you're getting so upset about, but whatever.

Comment: @j08691: I'm not "so upset" about anything; I'm trying to have a rational conversation with you about how the Stack Exchange Q&A model works, and I'm trying to decipher some of the things you're saying in response (many of which are contradictory, as I've pointed out). "But whatever."

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/typo. I don't see that it has to be "unintentional" (Waits for mod to come through and delete this whole comment thread)

Comment: @j08691: By the logic with which you interpret that dictionary entry, literally every programming mistake in the world is a "typo"! (Passive aggression doesn't suit you, sir!)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - settle this over a beer?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit comments are not meant for discussions either. That's what the chat is for.

Comment: @SebastianNette: Right, so why are you joining in a discussion in the chat section? :) See it's really easy to get drawn in. These can all be deleted now. I just wanted to point out, alongside where it happened, that an answer in the comment section is bad. That's it. That's all. None of all this drama business is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

elseif should have space in between.

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper, or scissors?");

var computerChoice = Math.random(1);

if (computerChoice <= 0.33){
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if (computerChoice <= 0.67 && computerChoice >= 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}
```

Comment: For some reason the first word was in the blind spot for me.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `else if` (not together)

**EDIT:** This is the working code

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper, or scissors?");

var computerChoice = Math.random(1);

if (computerChoice <= 0.33){
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if (computerChoice <= 0.67 && computerChoice >= 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you made up the keyword `elseif`, likely intending `else if`.

For future reference, the console also tells you *which* line the error is on; it's fairly easy after that to investigate each piece of technology on that line (check your spelling, look up meanings, etc.) to discover what you did wrong. In this case a very quick Google search for "javascript elseif" gets you [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4005614/560648).