# how to add if..else statement in my code

Tags: javascript

In my code, how can I add the if statement so it print different statements depend on different situtation. for example, I like to have a statement for the sum < 1, and else sum > 1. I try w3 school but the example if statement does not work for some reason

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Network Latency Calculator -->
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset = "utf-8">
  <title>Network Latency Calculation</title>
  <script>

     var firstNumber; // first string entered by user
     var secondNumber; // second string entered by user
     var thirdNumber; // third string entered by user
     var fourthNumber; // fourth string entered by user
     var number1; // first number to add
     var number2; // second number to add
     var number3; // third number to add
     var number4; // fourth number to add
     var sum; // sum of number1 and number2 and number3 and number4



     // read in first number from user as a string
     firstNumber = window.prompt( "Enter the Propagation time  (in milliseconds)" );

     // read in second number from user as a string
    secondNumber = window.prompt( "Enter the Transmission time  (in milliseconds)" );

    // read in third number from user as a string
     thirdNumber = window.prompt( "Enter the Queuing time  (in milliseconds)" );

    // read in fourth number from user as a string
     fourthNumber = window.prompt( "Enter the Propagation delay  (in milliseconds)" );

     // convert numbers from strings to integers
     number1 = parseInt( firstNumber ); 
     number2 = parseInt( secondNumber );
     number3 = parseInt( thirdNumber );
     number4 = parseInt( fourthNumber );

     sum = number1 + number2 + number3 + number4; // add the numbers





     // display the results
     document.writeln( "<h1>The network latency is " + sum + "</h1>" );



  </script>
```

Comment: Could you show your code with the example if..else statements please?

Comment: `if (condition) { "code if true" } else { "code if false" }`

Comment: `if` statements are Computer Programming 101 material. How can you know how to program and not know how to write a simple `if`?

Comment: @Barmar Everyone starts somewhere

Comment: OT but try and use "08" or "09" for one of your inputs. Then add a radix to your parseInt (`parseInt( firstNumber, 10 )`)

Comment: "does not work for some reason" - what did you try exactly? What happened exactly?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you might want to look here:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_writeln.asp

Right now you writing in the head of the html not in the body

```html
<body>

<p>Note that write() does NOT add a new line after each statement:</p>

<pre>
<script>
var NowDate = new Date();
var number1 = NowDate.getHours(); //added current hour 0-23
var number2 = 5; // second number to add
var number3 = 0.3; // third number to add
var sum = number1+number2*number3;
if (sum > 5){
    document.write("That's a");
    document.write(" big Sum ("+sum+")");
} else if (sum === 4) {
    document.write("Sum =");
    document.write(" 4");
}else{
    document.write("Sum is ");
    document.write("small ("+sum+")");
}
</script>
</pre>


<p>Note that writeln() add a new line after each statement:</p>

<pre>
<script>
document.writeln("Hello World!");
document.writeln("Have a nice day!");
</script>
</pre>

</body>
```

Comment: Link can expire over time. Please add the relevant code/info to your post so that future SO users can also benefit.

Answer (score 0):

After you get the sum, you could add an if-statement similar to this code if you so desire:

```
if (sum < 1) {
   document.write ("The sum is less than one");
} else if (sum > 1) {
   document.write( "The sum is more than one"); 
}
```

If you have more questions about if-conditional statements O'Reilly has a number of excellent technical books dealing with JavaScript.

```js
var firstNumber; // first string entered by user
 var secondNumber; // second string entered by user
 var thirdNumber; // third string entered by user
 var fourthNumber; // fourth string entered by user
 var number1; // first number to add
 var number2; // second number to add
 var number3; // third number to add
 var number4; // fourth number to add
 var sum; // sum of number1 and number2 and number3 and number4



 // read in first number from user as a string
 firstNumber = window.prompt( "Enter the Propagation time  (in milliseconds)" );

 // read in second number from user as a string
secondNumber = window.prompt( "Enter the Transmission time  (in milliseconds)" );

// read in third number from user as a string
 thirdNumber = window.prompt( "Enter the Queuing time  (in milliseconds)" );

// read in fourth number from user as a string
 fourthNumber = window.prompt( "Enter the Propagation delay  (in milliseconds)" );

 // convert numbers from strings to integers
 number1 = parseInt( firstNumber ); 
 number2 = parseInt( secondNumber );
 number3 = parseInt( thirdNumber );
 number4 = parseInt( fourthNumber );

 sum = number1 + number2 + number3 + number4; // add the numbers

if (sum < 1) {
   document.write ("The sum is less than one");
} else if (sum > 1) {
   document.write( "The sum is more than one"); 
}

 // display the results
document.writeln( "<h1>The network latency is " + sum + "</h1>" );
```

Comment: Do note that when the sum is equal to `1`, no message will be written. This may or may not be what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

First off, judging by your short description on what you want, I understand you want the statement of whatever you want to say after you calculate the total. To do that, it is really easy.

**Example:**

```
sum = number1 + number2 + number3 + number4; // add the numbers

if(sum > 1){
    //Your code
} else {
    //Your code
}
```

The reason I didn't put `else if` because if the sum is greater than one, it runs whatever statement you want it to run. If it isn't, then it will run the other, the `else` statement.

If you want to look at more `if/else` examples, you can go on this StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005614/elseif-syntax-in-javascript) and check the examples they have and how to use it.