# expected an identifier but instead saw 'else'

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I've been racking my brain over this for the past hour. Looked at examples from people asking the same question, but the error is persistent. Could anyone check out my code and see what's wrong? It's part of the Udacity intro to Javascript course. The mistake is in the ELSE line, but I honestly don't see anything wrong.

```js
var num = 60;

while (num => 0)
  if (num === 50) {
    console.log("Orbiter transfer from ground to internal power");
  }
elseif(num === 31); {
  console.log("Ground launch sequencer is go for auto sequence start");
}
elseif(num === 16); {
  console.log("Activate launch pad sound suppression system");
}
elseif(num === 10); {
  console.log("Activate main engine hydrogen burnoff system");
}
elseif(num === 6); {
  console.log("Main engine start");
}
elseif(num === 0); {
  console.log("Solid rocket booster ignition and liftoff!");
} else {
  console.log("T- " + num + " seconds");
}
num--;
```

Comment: should be `else if` not `elseif`

Comment: `num => 0` <-- wrong, you have a lot of typos in the code. Get an IDE that helps you

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["elseif" syntax in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005614/elseif-syntax-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the code the:

- While body must be between brackets {}
- Remove ";" after if else condition
- While condition must be >= instead of =>
- else if is two words

```js
var num = 60;

while (num >= 0){
  if (num === 50) {
    console.log("Orbiter transfer from ground to internal power");
  }
else if(num === 31) {
  console.log("Ground launch sequencer is go for auto sequence start");
}
else if(num === 16) {
  console.log("Activate launch pad sound suppression system");
}
else if(num === 10) {
  console.log("Activate main engine hydrogen burnoff system");
}
else if(num === 6) {
  console.log("Main engine start");
}
else if(num === 0) {
  console.log("Solid rocket booster ignition and liftoff!");
} else {
  console.log("T- " + num + " seconds");
}
num--;
}
```

Comment: Bravo on taking the time to elaborate :)