# Javascript only execute an "if" if the other "if" fails

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have started studying Javascript one month ago and I have a doubt. I'm programming a simple game that thinks of a random number and you have to guess it before you run out of attempts. To determine if the player guessed right or wrong the number, I have done the following (reduced code):

```
start(){
num=documentGetElementById("num").value;
attempts=10;
}
try(){
attempts=attempts-1;
if(num==random)documentGetElementById("message").innerHTML="You have won.";
if(attempts==0)documentGetElementById("message").innerHTML="You have lost.";
}
```

What happens here is that when you guess the number in the last attempt (1 attempt left) it says you have lost. So my question is: how to give priority to the if(num==random)...?

---EDIT---

Full code:

-HTML:

```
<div id="game">
  <div id="message"></div>
  <div id="status"></div>
  <div id="think"></div>
  <div id="start">
    <button id="start-button" class="boto-inici" onClick="start()"><span>START</span></button>
  </div>
  <div id="try">
    <label for="tryinput">Number:</label>
    <input type="text" id="tryinput"/>
    <button class="try-button" onClick="try()"><span>TRY</span></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

-JS:

```
function start(){
  document.getElementById("start").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById("try").style.display="block";
  document.getElementById("message").style.display="block";
  document.getElementById("status").style.display="block";
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="I've thought a number between 1 and 100";
  document.getElementById("status").innerHTML="You have 10 attempts.";
  random = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
  attempts=10;
}

function try(){
  attempts=attempts-1;
  document.getElementById("status").innerHTML="You have " + attempts + " attempts left.";
  var num=document.getElementById("tryinput").value;
  if(num>random)document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="The number you chose is bigger.";
  if(num<random)document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="The number you chose is smaller.";
  if(num==random){
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="You won.";
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML="The number I thought was the " + random + " .";
    document.getElementById("try").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("start").style.display="block";
  }
  if(attempts==0){
    document.getElementById("try").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="You lost.";
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML="The number I thought was the " + random + " .";
    document.getElementById("start").style.display="block";
  }
  if(isNaN(num)){
    alert("Please write a number.");
  }
}
```

It may contain some errors with the id's because I translated it. Hope it helps.

Comment: you could simply make the second if conditional, e.g. by making the two if statements to an `if ... else if`

Comment: Have you tried using `else if`

Comment: Use "else if instead" of "if" on the attempts one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a matter of *priority*. Both tests are running, in the order given.

Your problem is that you don't want to do the second test at all if the first one passes.

Use an `else` so the second test only runs if the first fails.

Comment: Oh, sorry for that. I didn't know how to name it. But, what if I have like lots of "if(num==random)" and lots of "if(attempts==0)"?

Comment: ["elseif" syntax in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005614/elseif-syntax-in-javascript)

Comment: @ArnauJiménez — Then you probably just want a lot of `else`s too.

Comment: But there are multiple attempts, not just one. If I put an else and the player fails it will say that he/she has lost.

Comment: @ArnauJiménez — I didn't say to remove the `if(attempts==0)` when you added the `else`.

Comment: @Quentin - So what you told me was to add a blank else?

Comment: @ArnauJiménez — No. For it to be blank you would have to remove `if(attempts==0)` (which I just explicitly said you shouldn't do) **and** `documentGetElementById("message").innerHTML="You have lost."`, which I have also said not to do.

Comment: @Quentin - Well, so how should it look like? I'm new to JS so a little help would be appreciated :)

Comment: You just add `else ` before the `if`

Comment: Before all the `if`...?

Comment: No. Before the `if` that you don't want to run if the answer is correct.

Comment: @Quentin - Thanks for your patience. That worked. I have added the full code btw.