# Rewrite if else into switch

Tags: c#, if-statement, switch-statement

I wrote some **if-else** statements like this:

```
   if (workedDays > 0 && workedDays <= 180)
   {
     x= 14;
   }

   if (workedDays > 180 && workedDays <= 540)
   {
     x= 28;
   }

   if (workedDays > 540 && workedDays <= 1068)
   {
     x= 42;
   }
   else
   {
     x= 56;
   }
```

I was trying to rewrite it as **switch** statement like this:

```
   switch (workedDays)
   {
     case (workedDays > 0 && workedDays <= 180):
       x=14;
       break;
     default:
       break;
   }
```

However, I am getting the error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'int'`.

How can I fix it?

Comment: workedDays is an int and your switch expressions evaluate to bools, so obviously this is not working. I think IF statements are better and more clear in this case, don't use switch if there is no real benefit.

Comment: switch can only use constants in C#. Not expressions like VB.Net. What is wrong with your if:s?

Comment: 'If' is more suitable in this situation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the `switch(true)` answer of @Jeroen might work, I suggest the following for readablity:

```
if (workedDays <= 180)
    x = 14;
else if (workedDays <= 540)
    x = 28;
else if (workedDays <= 1068)
    x = 42;
else 
    x = 56;
```

With the `else if` construction, there is no need to double check both minimum and maximum values.

Comment: I upvoted but would like to point out that you're missing the case where `workedDays <= 0`... though it seems that might not be correct in the OPs question?

Comment: @Williem Duncan. Thank you. I was trying to write it for purpose of readability. Nothing wrong in my if-else stamtent was. Just wanted to learn this way.

Comment: @paul I removed that for readability (and I also assumed it might be wrong to get `56` when `workedDays < 0`), but it's easily added.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I personally dislike having so many if-else-if's.

I usually follow the idea "three or more, use a for!"

So, I'd do this:-

```
class Program
{
  struct Data
  {
    public Data (int l, int u, int v)
    {
      lower = l;
      upper = u;
      value = v;
    }
    public int lower;
    public int upper;
    public int value;
  }

  static void Main (string [] args)
  {
    Data []
      // at the moment, this is coded into the source
      // it can be read from a file at run time instead
      data = { new Data (0, 180, 14), new Data (180, 540, 28), new Data (540, 1068, 42) };

    int
      // again, the default case is hard coded, it too can be loaded from a file
      x = 56,
      workedDays = 100;

    foreach (Data item in data)
    {
      if (workedDays > item.lower && workedDays <= item.upper)
      {
        x = item.value;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can then fill in the data array from a file so the search becomes run-time configurable so you don't need to rebuild the program to change the ranges and results.

Comment: This makes it into a horrible mess, would be a lot more useful with key-value pairs of maximum value and result, or if minimum and maximum is required, a collection of tuples.

Comment: What about readability? This feels like obfuscating the code.

Comment: @WillemDuncan: well, yes, I did allude to that in the answer if you read the comments. I was being brief and sort of language agnostic (and short on time). Feel free to replace the array of ints with array of structures.

Comment: @Skizz. I like your solution. My whole goal was to write something more readeable. With lot of if-else statements in code you have to look all of them one by one in order to determine them.And your solution is good for that purpose.

Comment: @WillemDuncan: Updated the source, now uses a struct with named data rather than the anonymous int array.

Comment: @Skizz. Would it be even better with following code: `public struct Data
{
    public int Lower { get; set; }
    public int Upper { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}` and then  `Data[] data = {new Data{Lower=0,Upper=180,Value=14},
                          new Data{Lower=180,Upper=540,Value=28},
                          new Data{Lower=540,Upper=1068,Value=42} 
                          };`

Comment: @black123: yes, that is a good solution, but does require newer versions of C#. I was trying to get the idea across rather than the implementation since the idea works equally well in most languages.

Answer (score 0):

do:

```
switch (true)
    {
        case (workedDays > 0 && workedDays <= 180):
            x=14;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Comment: This really shouldn't be done, to switch on true not only makes no sense but looks wrong.

Comment: Not saying this is the best way but this is the way to fix the error :), thats what he asked.

Comment: I have never seen this approach before and did a quick search on it and in some cases, including readability it seems to make sense. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765981/javascript-switchtrue `"Yes --- I think that you're being overly dogmatic about it, and I see a readability tradeoff either way. The switch statement gives me a visual cue that none of the following conditions will be evaluated, where with the series of ifs I have to notice the returns to realize that. I think switch(true) is a good and useful idiom and shouldn't be rejected, though this exact usage is not idea"` -linked

Comment: Does this compile in C#? I tried with LinqPad, and get the following error: `A constant value is expected`

Answer (score 0):

If you consider what you're asking the compiler to do you'll see why you've got the problem.

You're switching on workedDays which is presumably an int:

```
switch(workedDays:int)
{
   case (workedDays > 0 && workedDays <= 180):

   break;
}
```

Where you've got your case that is evaluated into a true or false result (a bool), so you're asking it to choose between integers but giving it a bool as a possibility!

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Switch statements can only be used with compile-time constants. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44905/c-sharp-switch-statement-limitations-why)