# Applying a Tax for a Certain Quantity

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to apply a tax for a certain quantity?
For example:

1: 0% tax
2-5: 5% tax
6-10: 10% tax
11-15: 15 % tax
16-20: 20 % tax

The problem is that the function always applies 5% tax for every quantity.
If a tax is applied, then the total should update, and calculate the tax and final total from there.

```
var tax = Math.round(price * 0.05 * 100) / 100
```

Comment: Did you try to use a switch statement and do your calculations inside the switch?

Comment: Please see [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and reduce your code to the minimum required to display the issue. Also, you do three rounding operations in a row, which is a bad idea. Do all the mathematics first, then round only at the very end since simple rounding is biased upward.

Comment: I updated the snippet so you can understand better.

Comment: @RobG - good point about including a *MCVE* (I have edited the question). But regarding the round operations, normally you pay (rounded) taxes for the (already rounded) price that you charge. Maybe in this case both operations are necessary. What you don't need is to round the final price.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement.

Wrap it up in a function together with the `round` logic:

```
function getTax( price ){
  var taxRate = 0;
  switch( true ){
    case ( price < 2 ):
    // or case ( price <= 1 ) depending on what you need
      break;
    case ( price < 6 ):
      taxRate = 0.05;
      break;
    case ( price < 11 ):
      taxRate = 0.1;
      break;
    case ( price < 16 ):
      taxRate = 0.15;
      break;
    default:
      taxRate = 0.2;
  }
  return Math.round( price * taxRate * 100 ) / 100;
}
```

And then call the function to get the returned value:

```
var tax = getTax( price );
```

`switch( true )` can be a confusing usage of this statement and not everyone like it. You can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2765981/5247200) and  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6665997/5247200). Go for `if` statements if you prefer it.

Also, beware of [some caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11832914/5247200) regarding the `Math.round` function.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you are using a hardcoded tax.

```
var tax = Math.round(price * 0.05 * 100) / 100
```

Here, in the `changeTotal` function, you should be using your desired tax value instead of simply multiplying by `0.05`.

Comment: Yes, but how can i assign different taxes for different quantities?

Comment: Create a function which computes the tax for a given value. For that you may use a switch or whatever logic may seem fit. I cannot write down that logic for you, though.