# Can you use functions within a switch case in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to be able to call a function on a switch case statement but I can't seem to figure it out. Example:

```js
switch(message.toLowerCase()) {
    // the startsWith would be an extension of the message.toLowerCase()
    // so that the case would be checking for message.toLowerCase().startsWith("pay")
    case startsWith("pay"):
        console.log(message)
        break
}
```

I have tried using case.function(), function(case), and case function(), but none of them work. Thanks!

Comment: How did you define `startsWith`?

Comment: @hev1 I didn't. That is a predefined function in js

Comment: Did you mean [`String#startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)?

Comment: This should work as long as your function returns a bool...

Comment: @hev1 Yes. I forgot to specify that the startsWith() would be an extension of the message.toLowerCase() that is in the switch statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Switch statements in JavaScript don't support pattern matching, they only do simple equality checks (the result of `lowerCase()` gets compared to the return value of `startsWith(...)` [if that function would exist]). You could do something like this though:

```
switch(true) {
  case message.toLowerCase().startsWith("pay"): // if this is true, the case matches
    console.log(message);
    break;
 }
```

You could also write some helpers to achieve more flexible pattern matching:

```
  const match = (...patterns) => value=> patterns.find(p => p.match(value))(value);
   const pattern = match => fn => Object.assign(fn, { match });
  const startWith = a => pattern(v => v.startsWith(a));

 match(
    startsWith("b")(console.error),
    startsWith("a")(console.log),
    startsWith("a")(console.error)
 )("abc")
```

Comment: I would not use the first solution is because it is bascily just a if else statement, which is what I was trying to avoid by using a switch statement.

Comment: what is a problem with `if-else`?

Comment: @jan the OP already seems to be aware of that option. Wether a switch statement or an if else if is cleaner is really a matter of personal preference.

Comment: @JanStránský I am going to be having a lot of if-else's stacked on top of each other, and I want it to be very fast. From what I know switch statements are a lot faster then else-if because instead of checking every single option until you get to the right one, (with if-else), a switch statement will look at the value and jump straight to the correct case, which is much faster.

Comment: This is wrong, in this case there won't be any difference. (and even in cases were it *could* matter, I doubt that this is even measurable)

Comment: Well ok then. I guess I'll just use the if-else's.

Comment: @Levi_OP Don't forget to save the `message.toLowerCase()` result into a variable. Otherwise you would need to execute this in every else-if statement, which would indeed make it slower. `const lowerMsg = message.toLowerCase()` (or override `message` if you don't need the original) then `if (lowerMsg.startsWith("play"))`, `else if (lowerMsg.startsWith("pause"))`

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use [switch(true)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765981/javascript-switchtrue).

```js
var m = message.toLowerCase()
switch(true) {
    case m.startsWith("pay"):
        console.log(message)
        break
}
```

Read the original thread for more details (e.g. that the `case` return value must be truely `true`, e.g. `1` would not work (but would work for `if-else`.

Also consider to use ordinary `if-else`, sometimes it might be more readable and maintainable than `switch` (and especially than this "non-standard" `swith(true)`)

Also consider using regular expression. From the OP it is not really clear what you are looking for.