# How does switching on computed values change runtime complexity?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, switch-statement

I have a switch statement which runs logic depending on the current url path. It has a default case which considers computed values (such as regex matches) if none of the other cases are matches:

```
const pathname = document.location.pathname;
switch (pathname) {
    case "/foo": //...
    case "/bar": //...
    case "/baz": //...
    default:
        if (/^\/user\/\w+\/likes/.test(pathname)) {
            // ...
        }
        else if (/^\/blog\/\d+/.test(pathname)) {
            // ...
        }
}
```

Someone suggested I change it to omit the `default` and use conditionals as my cases:

```
switch (true) {
    case pathname === "/foo": //. ..
    case pathname === "/bar": // ...
    case pathname === "/baz": // ...
    case /^\/user\/\w+\/likes/.test(pathname): // ...
    case /^\/blog\/\d+/.test(pathname): // ...
}
```

I want to identify which of these has the better runtime complexity. To be honest, I've never seen something like this before, so I do not know how it works under the hood. I know that *Java* compiles switch statements into lookup tables, but JavaScript is not compiled so it may not use lookup tables.

If JS *does* use lookup tables, the first option (using `default`) would likely perform better, since the case statements all use constant values which can be hashed. And if [this](https://medium.com/trabe/using-switch-true-in-javascript-986e8ad8ae4f) is correct when it states that expressions are evaluated before matches, then the second would potentially perform worse (depending the number of expressions).

So why might one have a better runtime complexity than the other? And how does it really work under the hood?

Comment: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Also runtime complexity != speed. An algorithm can have a constant `O(1)` complexity and run consistently for one entire week before it returns. Regardless of the input size. While a `O(n^2)` algorithm might outperform it for n <= 1000000.

Comment: @VLAZ yes, I am aware. I am interested in runtime complexity, not speed.

Comment: In terms of how they work, those two approaches imply doing pretty much the exact same computations. Use the one that looks better. Unless you need to run that function 1000 times on every refresh cycle, it makes absolutely no difference. And if you do need to run that function very often, it's time to look for broader algorithmic improvements.

Comment: Note that a good optimizer could turn that sequence of `===` comparisons to string constants into a hash lookup. But with only three comparisons, the hashing cost would not be worth it.

Comment: @Pointy  `the hashing cost would not be worth it`  Out of interest, I thought I test that the performance.  If your lookup can be made into a constant hash, just using an Object.  Even 3 comparisons in Chrome on Linux appears faster, especially if a nomatch or last item is searched.   Of course still not something you would do for that reason, but I was just curious. :)

Comment: @Keith modern JavaScript runtimes do all sorts of amazing things. One example is how `.indexOf()` works with arrays: it's unbelievably fast. Maybe because it's compiled clever code, I don't know. Seems like it's a linear search no matter how you roll it, but it's very fast.

Comment: @Pointy the three comparisons are just for the sake of the MCVE.  The actual code has 10 constant matches and 13 expressions, but I imagine this still wouldn't make a huge difference unless we were looking at a much larger number of comparisons.

Comment: Not sure of code complexity, but performance wise the first one is way slower..  Its maybe the reason someone suggested you change it.   PS, again this is Chrome / Linux so performance might be different, with different OS / Browser. etc.   My theory for the slowdown,  it's mixing `case` and `if`, and that's maybe not great for the V8 optimiser.

Comment: @CardinalSystem if you have a lot of those paths to examine, like in a "router", an approach that organizes the routes into a data structure so that you can do step-by-step traversal with a given actual path. That would allow you to do things like validate the collection of routes and find conflicts, etc.

Comment: That would almost certainly be *slower*, to be clear, but performance isn't everything. If you only need to check the path a few times, it doesn't matter at all, and the structural and maintenance benefits of a "smarter" system would easily outweigh performance considerations.

Comment: @Pointy these are good considerations for future projects on much larger scales, but the intent of my question is to *learn* how these two approaches to `switch` work behind the scenes. I am still wondering if JS even uses lookup tables, or if there's an entirely different approach that the interpreter takes to switches.

Comment: `switch work behind the scenes`,  How it works behind the scenes is browser dependent, if your curious to see how it really works you would need to look at the source code for Chromes JS engine,  and then again at Firefox, and again at Apples.   They could all do it differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both have equivalent runtime complexity. They are linear in the number of match expressions, which is constant.

> If [this](https://medium.com/trabe/using-switch-true-in-javascript-986e8ad8ae4f) is correct when it states that expressions are evaluated before matches, then the second would potentially perform worse (depending the number of expressions)

It doesn't say that **all** `case` expressions are evaluated before any of them is matched. The article just meant to emphasise that `case` evaluates any expressions, instead of working only with constant literals. Still, the expressions are evaluated and matched one after the other; they are not evaluated at all if a previous `case` already matched.

> I've never seen something like this before

`switch (true)` is discouraged and seen as a bad practice by many. Better use a normal `if`/`else` chain, which works just the same but is much easier to understand:

```
if (pathname === "/foo") { // …
} else if (pathname === "/bar") { // …
} else if (pathname === "/baz") { // …
} else if (/^\/user\/\w+\/likes/.test(pathname)) { // …
} else if (/^\/blog\/\d+/.test(pathname)) { // …
}
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer the questions which was asked. Thank you also for providing explanations.

Comment: *`switch (true)` is discouraged and seen as a bad practice by many.*  Do you have any references for that?  I hadn't seen it before.  I'm not much of a `switch` user, but this version doesn't seem to me any worse than the alternative.

Comment: @ScottSauyet It's more verbose, goes against the purpose of `switch` (which is pattern-matching a variable value against a list of constant values), and has the risk of forgetting to `break` or `return` which leads to fallthrough.

Comment: @ScottSauyet References: [1](https://medium.com/@samanthaadrichem/switch-true-is-bad-practice-a2615bb62a4e) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2765998) [3](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/nonsense-to-be-trendy-6100401243b2) [4](https://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/51574897dd5392f11d00032e#5159f6ea0f4b15f360002d51) [5](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/jrqjq0/comment/gbvv7q6/) [6](https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/htqokr/comment/fyie8bs/) [7](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=26779648)

Comment: @bergi: Thank you!  While I'm not entirely convinced, it's not a pattern I ever use myself, regardless.  A fan of expressions rather than statements, I tend to use nested conditional statements (ternaries) myself.